# Java, drawing all pixels on the screen with different colours with maximum performance

Tags: java, image, graphics, draw, pixel

I'm trying to draw a self-created 'image'(most likely a bufferedImage I reckon) using an array containing the colours in the format of hexadecimal numbers. And I'm talking about fullscreen, meaning about 1600x900 pixels. I've been succesfull in this attempt in multiple ways, for example:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    preRenderedImage.setRGB(0,0, width, height, graphiscHandler.colourArray, 0, width);
    g2.drawImage(preRenderedImage,0,0,width,height,this);
}
```

Another way I've found usefull was directly creating a bufferedImage instead of an array of colours. using bufferedImage.setRGB(x,y,colour) and drawing it in the end.

Both of these ways however were terribly slow, the first one for example didn't give me more as 20 fps.

Does anyone have a better way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends. Are the pixel colours all different? Do they all change or do only some of the, change per frame? Would it be easier to paint using shape primitives?

Comment: The pixel colours can differ greatly per frame and it won't be possible to use shapes I'm afraid.

Comment: First, I would have backing buffer of some kind that you switch in and out, allowing the paint method to remain free and fast (and just paint the screen), second I would use background thread to update the off screen buffer, modifying only those pixels that have actually changed, then I would swap the buffers. Rather then trying to set the pixel RGB, try drawing a line that is only 1 pixel wide directly to the BufferedImage's graphics context

Comment: Maybe something along the line of BufferedImage.getRaster.getDataBuffer and then directly manipulate the underlying data buffer. Might be faster then setRGB.

Comment: Changing only the pixels that have changed would require checking wether it's not allready that color, wouldn't that be more expensive as just setting it to that color?